# Getting info out of jQuery and assigning it to a variable for using it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having trouble getting country code out of jQuery.

I can get the users information using the IP. I want to get country code out of it and assign it to a variable so I can use it inside a function.

Here is the code I am using;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
      $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
      $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
      $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    }, "jsonp");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

  <hr/>
  <div id="ip"></div>
  <div id="address"></div>
  <hr/>Full response:
  <pre id="details"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I want to use the country code and assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/developers/responses#full-response), the country code is in a property called `country` in the response.  So you can access it just like you already do for `ip`, `city`, and `region`.

Simply assign that value to your variable:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    var countryCode = response.country; // <--- here
}, "jsonp");
```

Or if you need the value available outside the scope of that function, perhaps at window scope, define the variable in that scope and set its value in the AJAX callback:

```
var countryCode = ''; // <--- here
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    countryCode = response.country; // <--- and here
}, "jsonp");
```

Note of course that the value won't be immediately available, not until after the AJAX operation completes.